# Python - webscraping; dictionary data structure

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, key-value

I need to scrape this website (http://setkab.go.id/profil-kabinet/#) and produce an Excel file that has headers "Cabinet names" in column 1 and "Era" in column 2. That means each Cabinet name (e.g. Kabinet Presidensil, Kabinet Sjahrir I) should have its *own row* - alongside its respective era (e.g. Era Revolusi Fisik, Era Republik Indonesia Serikat).

This is the closest I've gotten:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('http://setkab.go.id/profil-kabinet/#')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

eras = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':"wpb_accordion_section group"})

setkab = {}
for element in eras: 
    setkab[element.a.get_text()] = {}

for element in eras:
    cabname = element.find('div',attrs={'class':'wpb_wrapper'}).get_text()
    setkab[element.a.get_text()]['cbnm'] = cabname

for item in setkab.keys():
    print item + setkab[item]['cbnm']

import os, csv
os.chdir("/Users/mxcodes/Code")

with open("setkabfinal.csv", "w") as toWrite:
    writer = csv.writer(toWrite, delimiter=",")
    writer.writerow(["Era", "Cabinet name"])
    for a in setkab.keys():
        writer.writerow([a.encode("utf-8"), setkab[a]["cbnm"]])
```

However, this creates an Excel file with the headers "Era" and "Cabinet names" in column 1 and 2, respectively. It fails to put each Cabinet name in a *separate* row. For example, it has 'Era Revolusi Fisik' in column 1 and lists *all* the cabinets *together* in column 2.

My guess is that I need to switch the key-value pairs somehow so that each Cabinet becomes a key and its era becomes its value - because currently it's the other way around. But I've tried and failed to do so. Any help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, the `cabinets[a]["cbnm"]` variable you use for writing is just a long `Unicode` so when you do `writer.writerow([a.encode("utf-8"), cabinets[a]["cbnm"]])` what actually happens is that you write the era at the first column and the whole Unicode in the single cell in the next column (even if you have `\n` in your string it does not prevent it from being writed in a single cell (`csv` actually think that you want the unicode to be in ONLY one cell so it puts `"` before and after the `cabinets[a]["cbnm"]` value to be sure it will actually be in one cell)), what you should do to write every cabinet value in another row is to use the `writerow` method separately for each desired row.
for example this code worked fine for me:

```
cabinets = setkab 
with open("cabinets.csv", "w") as toWrite:
    writer = csv.writer(toWrite, delimiter=",")
    writer.writerow(["Era", "Cabinet name"])
    for a in setkab.keys():
        writer.writerow([a.encode("utf-8")])  #write the era column
        cabinets_list = [i for i in cabinets[a]["cbnm"].split('\n') if i != '']  #get all the values that are separated by newline chars (if they aren't empty strings)
        for i in cabinets_list: writer.writerow([a.encode("utf-8"),i])   #write every value separately in the CABINET NAME row
```

as you can see I changed only the last 3 lines.

I hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks for your help! That code does indeed give the Cabinet names in separate rows - which is what I want. But it doesn't give each Cabinet's Era type in the column adjacent to it - which is also what I need. In other words, the 'Era' column should have separate rows but repeated Era types; the 'Cabinet name' column should have separate rows but unique Cabinet names. Currently the 'Era' column has only 6 unique rows. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: @mxcodes sure, I have updated the code (basically - instead of doing `writer.writerow(['',i])` (which create an empty column next to the cabinet column) we will do this `writer.writerow([a.encode("utf-8"),i])`)